# How the parity violation was shown in Experimental Test of Parity Conservation in Beta Decay?

Tags: experimental-physics, definition, parity

I read that in Experimental Test of Parity Conservation in Beta Decay by C. S. Wu, E. Ambler, R. W. Hayward, D. D. Hoppes, and R. P. Hudson, Phys. Rev. 105, 1413 – Published 15 February 1957 the parity violation was observed.

However, in the paper, the graphs were "Gamma-anisotropy" and "$\beta$ asymmetry". I don't know what those two terms represented, and how did were they related to the parity violation, which the paper mentioned that

> the sign of the ?asymmetric coefficient, $\alpha$, is negative,?

Also, what was "gamma-ansotropy"? and how does it related to the parity experiment?

How the parity violation was shown in Experimental Test of Parity Conservation in Beta Decay?

Comment: reading this will help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_experiment#Experiment